# What i am missing in HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am working on a site and want to rewrite URL by htaccess.

When i testing on local (xampp) then its working fine but when i testing online (Bigrock shared server) then getting error that "server can not handle this request".

What i want is URL like 
https://www.jeentourtravels.com/sight/jaisalmer-14.php

Its working local but online getting error ..... online this URL is working fine https://www.jeentourtravels.com/sight-jaisalmer-14.php

Please guide me that what i am missing .... or how can fix this issue.

My HTACCESS code is as below

```
**I want to use this code online.**

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule sight/(.*)-(.*)\.php$ sight.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]


**I am using currently this because above is not working on online server**

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule sight-(.*)-(.*)\.php$ sight.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Probably the usual problem with the partial overlap of fake path, and physically existing file - so disable `MultiViews`.

Comment: so as i see online "Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes" this code will disable mutiviews .... if i put it to my htaccess. Please guide me ..... that how can i disable multiviews or help by edit my htaccess code to check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe Thanks for your suggestion ..... its quite simple ..... because i am runner for htaccess and thats why i asked for this simple ..... I just put code and problem resolved now .....

Just added

```
+FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```